# PHP response. Second isset() call not working

Tags: php, isset

I have a simple PHP code that queries the DB and returns a list, which includes a new <kbd>submit</kbd> button, that will approve or not that `post`.

```
 if(isset($_POST['search'])){

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
  if($row['flag']==0) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<div class=\"dlcontainer2\">"; 
    echo "<div class=\"dlitem\">"; 
    echo "TourID: ";
    echo "<div class=\"dltourID\">{$row['tourID']}</div>"; 
    echo "Title: ";
    echo "<div class=\"dltitle\">{$row['title']}</div>"; 
    echo "City: ";
    echo "<div class=\"dlcity\">{$row['city']}</div>";
    echo "Description: ";
        echo "<div class=\"dldescription\">{$row['description']}</div>"; 
    //echo "<div class=\"dlapprove\">;
    echo "<input class=approve type='submit' name='submit' id=approve value='Approve'>"; 
    echo "</div>"; 
    echo "</div>"; 
    echo "<br>";

  }
}
}
```

And just below that, I make another `isset()` to see if the user clicks on the <kbd>Approve</kbd> button or not. But it is doing nothing:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST)) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
} else{
    echo "No true";
}
```

Comment: I see only one `isset`

Comment: Is the Submit button part of a form? I'm wondering how and where you want to send that info.

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking. By 'doing nothing' you mean what? The alert is not firing? Do you then see "No true" on your page? Also, your conditional && is redundant. If the `isset` is true, then `$_POST` is by definition not empty. Finally, where is `$message` defined? If you're just debugging, it's usually better to write to a log file or just dump the text into the html document rather than into a script tag; browsers can sometimes be more rigid about how/where they accept scripts on a page.

Comment: Hi Guys,thanks for taking the time. I reallt appreciate it.

The first isset() is on the top, and queries the DB just fine. 

So I get a list response. In that response I added a new button with a unique name for each list entry, that would have to allow me to press on it, and query again the DB and set a flag into that table from -1 to 1 (a sort of "approve").

The button is showing just fine but when I click on it, nothing happens although I have that isset() that I defined at the bottom of  my post. 

My question is, why isn't that isset() calling another POST form showing the alert?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem isn't the isset() but the !empty($_POST) I don't believe that $_POST on it's own returns anything.

Instead maybe try using !empty($_POST['submit']) which does what it looks like your code is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use this magic [`Heredoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) instead of many `echo`s

```
echo <<<"MyText"
<br>
<div class=\"dlcontainer2\">
    <div class=\"dlitem\">
        TourID: 
        <div class=\"dltourID\">{$row['tourID']}</div>
        Title: 
        <div class=\"dltitle\">{$row['title']}</div>
        City: 
        <div class=\"dlcity\">{$row['city']}</div>
        Description: 
        <div class=\"dldescription\">{$row['description']}</div>
        <div class=\"dlapprove\">
            <input class=approve type='submit' name='submit' id=approve value='Approve'>
        </div>
    </div>
<br>
MyText;
```

Second, you're using an extra unnecessary condition inside the second `IF-Statement`.

It should look like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { // or you can use $_POST['submit'] or !empty($_POST['submit']) or even $_POST
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
} else{
    echo "No true";
}
```